# How do I refer to parent element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, parent-child

I have more blocks:

```
<div class="static">
<div class="more-less">
    <div class="more-block">
        <p><?php echo StaticpageModule::getData(4)->body; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="button">        
        <a class="adjust" href="<?php echo StaticpageModule::getUrl(4); ?>">more</a>
        <div class="triangle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I refer to more-block class on adjust click?

I'm trying:

```
    $(".adjust").toggle(function() {
$(this).parents(".more-block").css("height", "auto").css("overflow", "visible");
}
```

Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.more-block` is not a parent of `.adjust`. It's a sibling of `.button`, `.adjust`'s parent. You need to change your query to this:

```
$(this).parent().prev().css("height", "auto").css("overflow", "visible");
       ^-------^ div.button
                ^-----^ div.more-block
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".adjust").toggle(function() {
    $(this).closest(".more-block").css("height", "auto").css("overflow", "visible");
}
```

Try using `closest` http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.prev()` like

```
$(".adjust").toggle(function() {
    $(this).prev('.more-block').css("height", "auto").css("overflow", "visible");
}
```

See this [**link**](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Answer (score 0):

.more-block is not parent rather it is sibling of the parent element.

`$(".adjust").parent().siblings(".more-block")`

this should work